# How to get the taxonomy titles from this WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have this WP_Query that's getting the terms that match the ID in the array.

How do I actually get the titles of these categories that match ID?

So for example I want to get the title of the category inside of the taxonomy 'interests' that has an ID of 23. I also then want to do the same for the category inside of the taxonomy 'co-curriculum' that matched ID of 45.

```
$current_category_arg = array(23,45);

$enrolments = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'enrolments',
    'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'interests',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $current_category_arg,
        ),
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'co-curriculum',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $current_category_arg,
        )
    ),
) );
```

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way to get those directly with WP_Query, you would likely have to write your own custom SQL query for that. But you can easily do it later on when you are processing the results, using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/

Comment: You can get the term details using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/ or get_term_by as CBroe mentioned above.

Note that your WP_Query will give you the post IDs corresponding to the post type enrolments that match the interests ids and the co-curriculum ids. It won't return the terms.

Comment: In both taxonomies you are looking for same term IDs ?!? WP_Query will get all posts of type enrolments having taxonomies interests AND co-curriculum with IDs 23,45 which its not possible and you wont get any results since the rule is AND